# django celery and rabbitmq access refused error

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

I have installed rabbitmq server and followed these steps:

```
sudo touch ~/.procfile

sudo vi ~/.procfile
```

and added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`

after that I added user and permission

```
sudo rabbitmq-server -detached
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user myuser mypassword
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser “.*” “.*” “.*”
```

and in my settings file I did :

```
BROKER_URL = “amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost”
```

It is working fine in my local. I am trying to send multiple emails at once.

To start celery I am using supervisor in my production.

```
sudo aptitude install supervisor
```

In production I have created my-project.config inside `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/my-project.conf`

My config file looks like:

```
[program:celery]
command=/var/www/html/myproject/venv/bin/python  /var/www/html/myproject/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO
environment=PYTHONPATH=/var/www/html/myproject
directory=/var/www/html/myproject
user=www-data
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
priority=998
```

It all works fine in local but in production when I try to send email with all this steps it gives me error saying

```
Exchange.declare: (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'celery' in vhost 'myvhost' refused for user 'myuser'
```

Why am I getting this error ? What is wrong here. it works fine in local with all this step while sending email but in production it gives me error

I need suggestion

Comment: Can you provide the configuration for rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf?

Comment: I have not written config for rabbitmq i.e /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf ...
It was working without that in my local

Comment: there is not any such file /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf .. do it come by default ?

Comment: rabbitmq-env.conf, if not found you should create one to customize the rabbitmq refer: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html